# Regular Expression that only integers or mixed numbers match

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use regex to validate user input with my JqueryUI validator.  I would like the user to ONLY be able to enter an integer or a correctly entered fraction.

I created regexr using \d+.\d+|\d+.$|^.0$|\d+/[1-9]+|\d+ \d+/[1-9]+ but it is not passing my tests because it accepts decimals and odd combos.  I got it from another SO post.

http://regexr.com/39hlm

**I would basically like the only acceptable input to be:**

an integer "1" or "200"

fraction "1/2" or "3/8"

mixed number "1 1/2" or "200 3/8"

**I would NOT like it to accept:**

any letters or other characters "number" or "5%"

odd combinations of correct entries "1 1/2 4" or "1 1/2 1/2"

How can I create proper regex that passes the tests on http://regexr.com/39hlm? (at the very least I would like it to accept integers and mixed numbers only and I can handle the other cases)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you can't do this through regex.

Comment: What is an improper fraction?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte A fraction whose numerator is larger than or equal to the denominator

Comment: @AvinashRaj why can this not be done with regex? for which match can regex not work?

Comment: regex dont know which one is proper and which one is improper fraction.

Comment: @AvinashRaj if we remove that variable is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without verifying "proper fractions" use this pattern

```
^(\d+(?:(?: \d+)*\/\d+)?)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cB3fQ1/2)

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you @alphabravo.  I'm surprised there isn't a simple website with commonly used regex patterns that's easy to search...